# Failing to autowire a repository field

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, javafx

I'm building a small desktop app using JavaFX and Spring Boot. I used [JavaFX Weaver](https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/javafx-spring-boot/) to integrate JavaFX and Spring Boot together.

I want to use the JPA repository Interface to access a MySQL database, however, I get an error when starting the app because of the auto wiring of the repository field.

[Console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tiUp.jpg)

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmjLh.jpg)

Service

```
@Service
public class ColorService {

    // I get the error when I add these 2 lines of code
    @Autowired
    private ColorRepository colorRepository;

    public List<Color> getColors(){
        return colorRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface ColorRepository extends JpaRepository<Color, Integer> {

}
```

Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="color")
public class Color {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="color_id")
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String colorName;

    public Color() {

    }

    public Color(String colorName) {
        this.colorName = colorName;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getColorName() {
        return colorName;
    }

    public void setColorName(String colorName) {
        this.colorName = colorName;
    }

}
```

Main App

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(JavaFxApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

JavaFX Main App

```
public class JavaFxApplication extends Application {

    private ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        String[] args = getParameters().getRaw().toArray(new String[0]);

        this.applicationContext = new SpringApplicationBuilder().sources(MainApp.class).run(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        FxWeaver fxWeaver = applicationContext.getBean(FxWeaver.class);
        Parent root = fxWeaver.loadView(MainController.class);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("css/style.css");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        this.applicationContext.close();
        Platform.exit();
    }

}
```

POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.diogo</groupId>
    <artifactId>habittracker</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>habittracker</name>
    <description>Habit Tracker</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.rgielen</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-weaver-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.diogo.habittracker.MainApp</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Try adding spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependency in maven pom instead of spring-data-jpa

Comment: I just can't believe it. It works. Thank you very much, man!!!

Answer (score 0):

The package of your class ColorRepository is not defined in component scan.

try to add : @ComponentScan({"package1","package2","..."})